# using mysql MATCH AGAINST to find no matches

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write my query so that it returns results where there is NO MATCH instead of one that returns results where it matches a word in a string

the following would look for instances that contained 'word'

```
AND MATCH(user_purchased) AGAINST ('word')
```

How would i modify this to look for instances that DID NOT contain 'word'.  Can this be done using MATCH AGAINST?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND NOT MATCH(user_purchased) AGAINST ('word')
```